# Cassandra - sstable2json "-f" option doesn't work

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 0.7.8, and I encountered an error message "`You must supply exactly one sstable`" when using command: `"bin/sstable2json [-f OUT_FILE] SSTABLE"`
my command is: `bin/sstable2json -f test.json /storage/cassandra/Test-f-35-Data.db`

So, does "`-f`" option work in this version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the `-f` flag was removed in 0.6 (see [CASSANDRA-766](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-766)). When I run sstable2json I see no mention of `-f` (on 1.0).  You should redirect the output to a file using your shell:

```
./bin/sstable2json /storage/cassandra/Test-f-35-Data.db > test.json
```